# How does <script src...> let other files access the libraries they import?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, src

In my html file, I'm doing this:

```
<script src="http://[node server]:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

And in my `file.js`, I can now use`socket.io` features.

How is the `socket.io` stuff made visible to `file.js`?

Comment: src just points to an external JavaScript file, in this case one from a node server and `file.js`, am I missing something here?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#create-a-script-from-a-node

Comment: Your browser is compiling all these functions into the DOM, all of that library will be available because it is actually included in your HTTP request.

Comment: The order is important - because the socket.io is added **before** file.js it is already loaded when file.js is used - [W3C reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html).

Comment: @PezCuckow Inside my file.js, I can use the `io` "class" from `socket.io` without doing or specifying anything. How is the socket stuff made visible to my js file?

Comment: The `socket.io.js` file, which is guaranteed to *run before* `file.js` (without the async flag, scripts are executed *in document order*), performs a *side-effect* upon the global scope (`window` object) - in this case is added the `socket.io` "namespace" which can be used. All the scripts in a page share the same global `window` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any script included in this way doesn't run in it's own context. Instead all scripts are executed within the context of the window that loaded them, meaning any objects or methods loaded in one script will be available in other scripts executed within the same window.

The order matters here, too. If `file.js` was included first, any references to objects or functions defined in `socket.io` would be undefined. That is, unless you have some sort of delayed execution mechanism in `file.js` which waits until the rest of the document is loaded to execute.

And, of course, this also applies to inline scripts. For example:

```
<!-- defines myFunc -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    myFunc(); // call myFunc
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you've come from a include strict language it's a little odd in thought.  Javascript is in global scope, so as long as you include a javascript file before referencing it in a 'lower' file you'll have access to everything from the first javascript.

Think of it as pasting it all into one big single file, I guess.... :)